# Not able to create login 401 error on login authentication error https://cis-dev1.manageamerica.com/Account/LogOn

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, qa-developer, browsers

https://cis-dev1.manageamerica.com/Account/LogOn

User :- cis-dev
Password:- UiCD!s5s3ieQ

Comment: Did you get this password from the developers?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't share credentials on public websites, it is not safe
2. In order to perform login:

   - Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it as follows:

     [image]
   - Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and configure it like:

     [image]
   - You can double check that the request is successful (or not) using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

     [image]

---

Going forward instead of creating a test plan manually you could consider recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), it should generate proper HTTP Request sampler and HTTP Header Manager configuration.